# Prove that if f '(x) ≠ 0 for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. , then f is one-to-one. Also, give an example to show the converse of this is false.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Hi guys I have run into another dead end! This is a practice problem for my exam review in my first year calculus class. Any help would be great. Thanks for all your help!

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function.

(a) Prove that if f '(x) ≠ 0 for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. , then f is one-to-one. (Hint: Use the mean
value theorem.)

(b) Give an example to show that the converse to (a) is false.

Comment: Can you at least do (b)? There’s are very simple polynomials that do the trick.

Comment: Maybe I should not have given away so much below. What do yous think?

Comment: Yes I have, my teacher explained the mean value theorem. It seems like a pretty simple and obvious theorem but still, I'm not really sure how to answer this problem.

Comment: Idea on why this is true: $$f'(x) \ne 0 \forall x\in\Bbb{R} \iff (f'(x) \gt 0 \forall x\in\Bbb{R}) \text{ or } (f'(x) \lt 0 \forall x\in\Bbb{R})$$ That is, you're either constantly increasing or constantly decreasing--the curve cannot "double-back" on itself. (This doesn't help to prove the idea, but it lets you visualize why it is true.)

Comment: There's no guarantee that $f'$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Using the mean value theorem, given $x \neq y$ in your domain, there is a point $z$ in (x,y), with  $\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(z)$ . How can $f'(z)=0$?. For $b$, think of $x^3$. Can you show it is $1-1$?

Answer (score 1):

And for the second let $f(x)=x^3$. Then $f$ is $1-1$ but $f'(x)=3x^2$ and $f'(0)=0$.